# PSTextFieldSpecifier return key?

Tags: iphone, settings

i have noticed that a PSTextFieldSpecifier in any Settings.bundle has the following issue:
The default keyboard (KeyboardType property set to Alphabet), does not dismiss keyboard when i hit "return" button...Is there a way to dismiss the keyboard when editing such a field  ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out that this can't be done...oh well

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a lot of them and can group them somehow then you could use Child Panes for Text Fields - Then at least you have the chance to dismiss the keyboard by using navigation panel BACK button :)